# Direction on passing values to the data access object

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-fragments, repository, dao

I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of users.
when a user is clicked the `Fragment` is changed to a second `Fragment` with another `RecyclerView` (contains favorite songs of users from first `RecyclerView`).  both of the lists are from the same table in the same SQLite database.

The issue I'm dealing with is that I want the second `RecyclerView` to list the songs only associated with the user name which was clicked in the first `RecyclerView`. So I want to filter the database rows by `userName`.  I don't know how to pass the `userName` to the DAO.  I need some direction on how to go about doing so.  I know I have to pass an argument from the `itemListView` that was clicked... but that is where I get stuck. I don't believe I should pass the argument using the navigation component because that only works between fragments?  Not really sure how to proceed and I can't find any tutorials online in kotlin. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: If you use the Room Libary have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-params
on how to pass a value to a query. Otherwise, you just have to concatenate the value into your query string.

Comment: My stopping point is the steps prior to this.  In the example you referred to, 'minAge' is passed to the query from the repository.  The repository is sent the minAge value from the ViewModel I assume.  This is the point I'm confused about.  How do I get the value from the UI to the view model to the repository and then to the DAO?  Do i use NavComponent arguments?  Or do I use a fragment bundle?  Does this fragment bundle have to be created in a companion object?  (These are all techniques which seem to come up as I research, but I don't fully understand them.)  An example would help.